# Filter in openerp

Tags: odoo

How to filter many2one field in openerp.

```
_columns = {
   'hello': fields.selection([('1','one'),('2','two')],'hello'),
   'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product',
                                 'Product',
                                 domain=[('type','=',hello)])'
   ...
}
```

If assume product.product have field called type which is also selection and its value same as hello does it work in xml or python??

Comment: Your question could use more detail. Tell us what exactly you're trying to do. Example data really helps clarify the question.

Comment: @shahjapan

''hello:fields.selection([('1','one'),('2','two')],'hello'),
'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', domain=[('type','=',hello)])' 

if assume product.product have field called type which is also selection and its value same as hello  does it work in xml or python??

Comment: You should edit your question instead of answering with a comment

Answer (score 8):

you can try the `domain` attribute of `fields.many2one` as below

`'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', domain=[('purchase_ok','=',True)], change_default=True),`

alternative way -> you can provide domain in your XML View as below,

`<field name="product_id" domain="[('purchase_ok','=',True)]"/>`

Comment: ''hello:fields.selection([('1','one'),('2','two')],'hello'),
'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', domain=[('type','=',hello)])'

if assume product.product have field called type which is also selection and its value same as hello  does it work in xml or python??

Comment: I think you want to change the domain of product_id (M2O) based on another field `hello` if so you need to write an `on_change` attribute on field `hello` in your xml and in python write respective function `onchange_hello` should return appropriate `domain` for field `product_id`, for detailed example see the existing module purchase -> method `product_id_change`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the domain in the view file which you want the many to one field to be filtered. For e.g. if you want to filter suppliers from the customers list just give the following in the view.

```
:domain="[('supplier','=',True)]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `context` or `domain` parameters described in the [developer book](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/openerp_fields.html). I haven't used them, but you can probably find examples in the core modules. The best description of `domain` syntax is on the [`orm.search()` method](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html#osv.osv.osv.search).

Answer (score 0):

I think u want to filter product.product according to hello fields right. so write the onchange method on hello filed in xml and in method, filter the product id which type is match to hello filed value.

In function/method u can add all the ids which type is matches to hello filed value, in the list and after return this list to product_id.

Comment: how to write it when Domain filter with more than 2 conditions ?

Comment: yes, it will work for one and more than one condition, bcz we generating list of ids which are satisfied all the condition which we want, and this list will return...