# How can I change the choices in an OpenERP selection field based on other field values?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I have a form with four fields:

- Crop - selection
- Active From - date
- Active To - date
- Block Area - selection

How can I make the available options in Block Area depend on the values the user selects for the other fields?

Comment: You question is quite hard to follow: it sounds like it could benefit from some code examples explaining the current state of your problem.

Comment: I tried to clarify your question, @Santu. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: I notice that you haven't accepted any answers to your other questions, @Santu. If any of the answers were helpful, please mark them as accepted by clicking on the big check mark next to each answer. That helps other people who have the same question, and it's a way to thank the people who helped you.

Comment: try on_change function i think it works

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can do it with a selection field, but you can change the domain of a many-to-one field when another field changes value. You might also be able to just use the other fields in your BlockArea field's domain, and not have to change it at all. Look at the way the [partner address screen](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/5.0/view/head:/bin/addons/base/res/partner/partner.py?start_revid=2181#L262) sets the domain for the state_id field. You might find [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5150859/4794) helpful.

If you do need to change the domain when another field changes, then [the `on_change` event](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/events/events.html#on-change) can include a `domain` entry in the dictionary it returns.

I found [a discussion thread](http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic4475.html) that says you can use the selection widget on a many-to-one field, so that might work for you if you set a `domain` for the field. I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

To limit the available options based on other field values you can use the `domain`. As an example, this is used on the standard module `project_issue`:

Quoting the relevant lines:

```
class project_issue(crm.crm_case, osv.osv):
    _columns = {
        'project_id':fields.many2one('project.project', 'Project'),
        'type_id': fields.many2one ('project.task.type', 'Stages', domain="[('project_ids', '=', project_id)]"),
    }
```

In this example the `type_id` available options are fetched from `project.task.type` table, depending on the value of the `project_id` field.

Answer (score 1):

Try on_change function.. create  an on_change function and at the end of the function return the domain condition for the field block_area
for example

```
def onchange_for_block_area(self,cr,uid,ids,crop,from_date,to_date,context):
    domain=[]
    #
    #some statements for finding the domain
    #
    return {'domain':{'block_area': domain}}
```

provide the onchange function on the fields crop, from_date and to_date