# Dynamic selection box in openerp

Tags: python, odoo

How can i make dynamic selection box in which options act according to on_change functionality. I want to use this functionality on wizard.

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8325315/4794). Not sure if `on_change` is supported in a wizard.

Comment: i searched it on web and found i can use on_change on wizard by declaring wizard as osv_memory rather than wizard.interface. But still got stuck in dynamic selection.

Comment: You will get the dynamic selection in next stage of the wizard not in same stage.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the selection field into many2one field to a new little model you create for this purpose.
You then return a domain in the on_change function, to set some condition to filter possible values.
If you don't want the options (Create, Create and Edit...) on the many2one widget, you can always use the module: https://github.com/0k/web_m2x_options to get rid of them