# How to make domain dynamic in OpenERP

Tags: dynamic, odoo

I want to give a dynamic domain equation in view or in field definition in .py.

like

```
<field name="product_id" domain="[('name','in',get_names)]"/>
```

product_id is a many2one field.

get_names is function that creates a list at run time.

Its showing an error - "name 'get_names' is not defined"

Any Ideas.

I have also tried the following.

```
'product_id': fields.many2one('mymodule.relation.model','Title',selection=get_names)
```

This displays all entries in mymodule.relation.model. The only thing it does is to validate if value selected/submittted by user belongs to the 'get_names'.

Comment: Can I know on which basis get_names will create name ?

Comment: It will search another table at runtime & build the list & return it.

Comment: you can get the name in a field and assign it to the domain in the view.

Comment: What if its a list like [('name','in',get_names)] ? Will a char field work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inherit the fields_view_get() function and manage the domain condition. Please check these posts

1. [How to create a dynamic view on OpenERP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569828/how-to-create-a-dynamic-view-on-openerp/6731739#6731739)
2. [How can I change the choices in an OpenERP selection field based on other field values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325315/how-can-i-change-the-choices-in-an-openerp-selection-field-based-on-other-field/10362861#10362861)

Answer (score 2):

1- You can use function field like this:

```
def _get_domain(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    record_id = ids[0] 
    # do some computations....
    return {record_id: YOUR DOMAIN}
```

and function field:

```
'domain_field': fields.function(_get_domain, type='char', size=255, method=True, string="Domain"),
```

And  use the name of the field in xml (domain attr):

```
<field name="product_id" domain="domain_field" />
```

2- you can use 'fields_view_get':

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(taskmng_task, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
    for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='project_id']"):
        # do some computations....
        node.set('domain', YOUR DOMAIN)
    res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a function or method in the domain expression, only object fields.
It's not equivalent, but closest thing is to create a function field to use in the domain expression.

Answer (score -3):

As Don't know your exact requirement .but may be any one from these 2 can help you

http://ruchir-shukla.blogspot.in/2010/11/domains-value-depending-on-condition.html

or check the Account Invoice product onchange . You can return domain from the onchange.

Comment: I checked your link.It is domain based on condition.My requirement is that the right argument in domain should be dynamic.

Comment: dynamic but based on some field value? the write onchang of that field and return domainexample is there in invoice line product onchange sale order line product onchange

Comment: It would be nice to include your answer here instead of posting it in a blog.

Comment: It would be great if you check the blog date. It was 2 years back I created blog for same topic , here I AM JUST GIVING REF. OF SAME.